# Remote accessing router with static IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I've got a server running on raspberry pi that is connected to the router. The router has static IP and the routing rule: "Route [static_pi]:22 to [raspberry_lan_ip]:[server_port]". Now I'm far from my router but I have to do some changes in its settings page (that's available by "192.168.1.1" in LAN). Any ideas how to do it?
My router model: ASUS RT-AC68U

Comment: What is the router model?

Comment: @kisk ASUS RT-AC68U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote access is something that is offered on most routers, however it has to be setup and configured from your local LAN first before you can use it remotely.

If you have remote access to your RasPi server, you could remote to that and in turn access your local LAN.

[Here](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1000926/) is the setup process for the remote router access.